# C++ Class Abstract Coordinates

Tags: c++, class

So my goal is simple,
I want to have an x and y in the base class,
 and then have my other class own those values as well

```
class Skeleton
{
private:
    float x, y;

public:
    Skeleton(float x, float y);
};

class Object : Skeleton
{
    float getX() const
    {
        return x;
    }
};
```

By the way, I'm sort of new to C++
I come from Java and want to learn C++!

Comment: Yes, that's called **inheritance**. So, what is your problem exactly?

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings I think OP might be looking for best practices as well. Let him clarify.

Comment: Use `protected` instead of `private` in the `Skeleton` class. `protected: float x, y;`

Comment: One of the better ways to learn C++ is from a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).  Java and C++ are very different languages (both very good languages), but what you've learned in Java may not be applicable in C++.

Comment: Perhaps the answer you've gotten is an answer to whatever it is you're asking, but it's very hard to tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `protected` [access specifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/access) instead of `private` to allow classes which derive from your base class to access certain member functions and variables.

Also you'll need your derived classes `constructor` to call the base classes `constructor`.

```
class Skeleton
{
protected:
    float x, y;

public:
    Skeleton(float x, float y);
};

class Object : Skeleton
{
public:
    Object( float x, float y ) : Skeleton{ x, y } { }

    float getX() const
    { 
        return x;
    }
};
```

Comment: You also need `class Object : public Skeleton` (or `class Object : protected Skeleton`).

Comment: or `struct Object : Skeleton`